# PHP/HTTP non non-stateless

Tags: php, database, http, data-storage

**PHP** uses **cookies, sessions or databases (and ORMs)** in order to remember data (so they are not lost after single HTTP request). However, in Java (I mean servlets etc.) there is another solution: in brief you may choose for an object different scopes (how long it exists). Besides of session-scope or simple single HTTP-request "life" (scope), it can "live" during whole HTTP-server runtime and can be initialized at the startup of the HTTP-server.

Data can be therefore shared between different users / sessions, and no database requests are required (causing decrease of efficiency of the whole web-application). (I mean they're not required when HTTP-Server is already running - the object and its state is "remembered").

(And I do as much as I can to decrease SQL requests, using even PHP arrays for frequently read, but actually never modified DB data).

What I need in PHP is a way to:

1. **Remember (store somewhere)** data that can be changed and shared between many users, but not into DB
2. Without using sessions (nor cookies) I want to **have multiple data-informations for many requests** (etc. AJAX no single, but many requests to the same URL), which of course must be stored somewhere else for some time. For instance, I want to read all data (rows) with a single SQL request, remember them for a short period in PHP, and only then, one by one row, send responses with, say, each row in seperate response into appropriate AJAX function

Anyone can give me some hints how can I achieve this in PHP, preferably easiest possible way?

Comment: Handling this sort of thing efficiently is literally what a database is for.

Comment: I did it with database earlier. But when you have even 50 or 100 rows to read from DB, your application will run very slow, when you have to do each SQL request for each AJAX request. So I'd like to have one SQL request, with rows saved (in PHP or somehwere for a short period) for many AJAX requests, so that DB is used only once. In Java as I mentioned you can simply use object with appropriate scope.

Comment: Using temporary files is not impossible. Normally they are buffered by the operating system, and you can also use tmpfs filesystem from memory.

Comment: You also have the options to store in-memory objects to php accelerators ( xcache, eaccelerator ) or use shmem or some support library for it.

Comment: Thanks anttir I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preface to this answer (which I'm sure you've already grasped), PHP's execution model essentially 'restarts' the process between requests and as such storage of anything cross-request in PHP alone is unachievable.

That leaves you with a few options, and they're all really 'strengths' of database:

1. Use a simple key-value in-memory persistance layer, like memcached or Redis
2. Use a noSQL solution with a bit more structure (and consistency should this be required) but that's still working in-memory and is comparably quicker than an RDB
3. Use an RDBMS because it'll work great, and the quantity if traffic you'll need to topple a well designed schema on moderate hardware is probably much higher than you think

HTH

Comment: Ad 1. I will look at this solution closer, thanks. Ad 2. I can't see much different solution here than using that from Ad. 1? Ad 3. It didn't in my case. See, the problem is the fact of many SQL requests - and the DB-server is on different physical server (with some limitations) than Apache/PHP. I want to overcome this "physical" problem by sending to Apache/PHP only one DB-response.

Comment: #2 is suitable for use cases where you might want to store data with persistance across restarts, but without involving your RDB. From what you've said, though, you're looking to build more of a cache of data you're pulling from elsewhere - in that case working with #1 is probably your winner. Just be careful about data living in a cache after it's been updated on the database, how often you refresh it, etc. HTH.

Comment: Ok. Can you please give me some more concrete example of solving #2 case? (It sounds somewhat abstract to me for now).

Comment: I would quickly digress in to noSQL vs. SQL, a topic easily researched with the Google's help, but in your case I suppose you could store data for which relational integrity etc. is not essential and with which you don't want to labour your external RDB server. What precisely this data might be is domain specific.